# How to use PowerShell to Connect to the RSA Authentication Manager API

Tags: powershell, api, rest

I am trying to register new RSA agents automatically via the RSA Authentication API. I have the RSA AM (Authentication Manager) API Access ID & Access Key from the console. How would I pass these via PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod/Invoke-WebRequest Headers to complete the createAgent operations?

Comment: This sounds like a request for someone else to read the documentation for you? Most RSA APIs expect the client to embed the api key in a `client-key` header, but the authentication flow for obtaining the API key based on your access ID and/or access key depends on the product and version, so.... go look it up in the documentation for your given version of RSA?

Comment: I have reviewed the documentation @MathiasR.Jessen. I have made plenty of API calls to other applications that utilize the BASIC authentication type in the header (i.e. basic UN/PW). RSA appears to utilize some sort of header parameter for the accessKey using X-API-Token or something similar, but I don't know how to construct the request/header. The RSA API calls are all written in Java. I promise this isn't a request for someone else to read the documentation. If anything, a request for guidance to help me learn more in this area of API calls.